# Managing Azure Cloud Services as part of a Resource Group

Tags: azure, service, cloud

I have several App Services, and storage accounts set up in Azure. We have a Resource Group, which is a handy way to bundle together all the services and storage - for example, for tracking billing (other teams use the same subscription).

Now, I want to add a new Cloud Service, and have it included in the Resource Group. But then I see the Cloud Service listed at the same level as Resource Groups, which makes no sense.

Is it possible to include Cloud Services inside a Resource Groups, along with our App Services - and if not, what's the rationale?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "see the Cloud Service listed at the same level as Resource Group"?

Answer (score 1):

Currently azure cloud services( web roles and worker roles) are not part of the Azure resource manager feature. Hence you cannot add a cloud service to a resource group. This is a requested feature in the azure feedback portal. You can go add your comments and cast your vote.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169386-cloud-services-web-and-worker-role/suggestions/7899432-add-cloud-services-as-an-available-resource-when-w